# Rails model how to check that two objects are not equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec-rails

I have 2 models, Bid & Package. How can I validate in the model that this can never be true?

```
bid.user == bid.item.user
```

so that this unit test can pass

```
describe "user cannot bid on their own package" do
    @bid.user should_not equal @bid.item.user
end
```

I am trying to make sure that a user cannot bid on their own items.

Edit:
My model is

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :package

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :package_id, presence: true  
    validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }

    .....

end
```

Comment: Compare the user ids, they are unique.

Comment: how can I write that in the bid.rb model?

Comment: `if bid.user.id == bid.item.user.id` don't save it and/or raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
validate :cannot_bid_on_self

def cannot_bid_on_self
  if user.id == item.user.id
    errors.add(:user, "can't bid on own item")
  end
end
...
```